# Dynamically create forms based on JSON object

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm currently working on an app that allows users to answer questions about themselves. I'm retrieving these questions from an API. Now, I want to create a form with these questions as the inputs. I'm currently using something similar to the simple form described here: http://learnangular2.com/forms/

Now, I'm wondering if it's possible to create this form based on the questions my API serves. I can get a JSON object with all the questions, but is it possible to create a for loop that populates the form with the questions in the JSON object? This part of the code in the example above gives me the impression that it is not possible this way:

```
this.loginForm = fb.group({
  email: ["", Validators.required],
  password: ["", Validators.required]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Template-Driven forms](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/21/template-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html)

Use `ngFor` to loop thru questions and create `ngControl` for each.

`ngControl` names will be set to `Question1`, `Question2` ...

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logForm(form.value)">
  <div *ngFor="#question of questionsList; #i = index">
    <label>{{question}}</label>
    <input type="text" [ngControl]="'Question' + i">
  </div>
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`logForm` method, inside corresponding component, will get object containing key (`ngControl` name) and value (corresponding input value)